# How long has she been seeing him? / How long has she known him?

Tags: idiomatic-language

A: My ex-wife has a boyfriend.

B: How long has she known him? / How long has she been seeing him?

What would be the most likely question in this context? One of my suggestions?

Comment: What meaning do you want to convey as they are different?

Comment: How long they have been a couple.

Comment: She might have known him as a friend/acquaintance while still married, and then started a romance after the divorce.

Comment: This may just be AmE but the best and most common way would be `How long have they been together?` This directly implies their relationship status as intended.

Answer (score 3):

Neither of them is unambiguous about their being a couple.

> How long has she known him?

This could date back well into the past before they became a couple. They might have been at infant school together for instance.

> How long has she been seeing him?

This is closer but they could be seeing one another, dating in fact, for some time before they became a couple officially. People sometimes do not make the relationship public until they are sure, for some meaning of sure.

The least ambiguous way to phrase it is

> How long have they been an item?
> How long have they been a couple?
> How long have they been together?

The last one was suggested in comments be Eli Harold and is also current in BrE.

Comment: This may just be AmE but the best and most common way would be `How long have they been together?` This directly implies their relationship status as intended.

Comment: Yes and no.  Yes about 'known', but no about 'seeing'.  If they're dating, they're a couple.  What is an 'official couple'?

Comment: 'Seeing' here is a euphemism for something else, in which the eyes are not the main organs involved. Also, 'dating' may be a rather prim way of expressing the likely situation, unless the participants are 1950s teenagers.

Answer (score 2):

Both are fine.

?(see= meet) or

How long has she known him?  or

How long have they been a couple?